# Can someone please tell me what model this mikuni carburetor is?

Tags: carburetor

I've been doing some work on this one, and I'd love to find a diagram or some type of parts book for it. Thanks!

Edit: It came off of a suzuki df115 outboard. There are no letters or anything on the carb that I could find. I'm not overly familiar with the terminology, but it seemingly has one jet? and a small black float upon opening the float bowl.

[image: 1]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: did you forget to post the image?

Comment: No other numbers or letters on it  anywhere? What did it come off of?

Comment: What does it come off of? Are there any other markings on it? One barrel? Side draft?